# How to list incoming data in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to list the data from the service I use as it is in the example. Can you help me?

[image]

My code:

```
 import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class CustomersTab extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      token: "",
      isLoading: true,
      dataSource: null
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    tokenner()
      .then(responseJson => {
        const token = "Bearer " + responseJson.result.token;
        this.setState({ token });
        fetch(
          "apiurl",
          {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
              Accept: "application/json",
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
              Authorization: token
            }
          }
        )
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(responseData => {
            this.setState({
              isLoading: false,
              dataSource: responseData.result
            });
          });
      })
      .catch(error => console.warn(error));
  }};
  render() {

        return (
        <View>
          <Text>
            I WANT LİST DATA HERE
          </Text>
        </View> )}}
```

I tried to do it myself, but I could not build the loop structure. Only one data is displayed every time. What should I do?

Comment: save the data that you recieve from server in an array,and then use it in Flatlist data.

Comment: How? Can u make en expamle?

Comment: here you can save the datas you recieve and save in an array like "data":
if (response.data.status == "success") {
                        console.log(response);
                        if (response.data.data.length > 0) {
                            this.setState({data: response.data.data });
                        } else {
                            alert("");
                        }

then use it in Flatlist like this:

 <FlatList
         data={this.state.data}
.
.
.
.
/>

Answer (score 0):

you have to do something like this. Change id to what you want to display.

```
return (
  <View>
    <ListView
    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
    renderRow={data => <Text>{data.id}</Text>}
    />
  </View>
);
```

Comment: How can I make it more visual?

Answer (score 0):

Please Import the View and Text from react native.

```
import {
  Text,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

constructor(props: Object) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
    dataSource: []
   }    
};
```

```js
/* dataSource = [
     { "id": "1", "title": "Star Wars", "releaseYear": "1977" },
     { "id": "2", "title": "Back to the Future", "releaseYear": "1985" },
     { "id": "3", "title": "The Matrix", "releaseYear": "1999" },
     { "id": "4", "title": "Inception", "releaseYear": "2010" },
     { "id": "5", "title": "Interstellar", "releaseYear": "2014" }
   ]
*/

renderMovieList(){
  return  this.state.dataSource.map((movie, index) =>
    <View 
      key={movie.id} 
      style={{ height:50 padding:10}}>
      <Text> movie.title</Text>
      <Text> movie.releaseYear</Text>
    </View>
  )
}
render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent:'center'}}>
        {this.state.dataSource.length ? this.renderMovieList(): null}
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Comment: {this.state.dataSource.length ? this.renderMovieList(): null}
is not working?

Comment: initialize the dataSource with empty Array. I have updated the answer please check it

Comment: responseData.result is an array or Object.